# Input shape for Keras LSTM/GRU for floats

Tags: keras

I'm sorry for asking that stupid thing. I can't apply answers from other questions to my task.
Currently I got well-known error:

```
expected lstm_input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (7491, 1025)
```

My data:

matrix - 1025 **float** numbers in row. 7491 rows

So how to make it 3d? Or am I trying to use wrong layer model?

Comment: The specification of your data is ambiguous. Can you clarify how your data looks like? For example, shows us the shape tuple.

Comment: `[array([  3.11176137e-07,   1.67789310e-07,   9.64585638e-07, ...,
         4.20807282e-06,   1.41265843e-06,   4.50570468e-07], dtype=float32), array([  7.58383294e-08,   2.14132754e-07,   9.35328899e-08, ...,
         1.69262967e-06,   2.00145996e-06,   2.90755770e-06], dtype=float32), array([  3.73906559e-08,   4.06536920e-08,   4.66051304e-08, ...,
         7.32231968e-07,   3.70042414e-07,   4.31219220e-08], dtype=float32)]`
numbers are features. 1025 features from 1 second sampling. 7491 rows - data for 7491 seconds

Comment: Ah. You need to have an explicit time dimension and a batch dimension. Reshape your data to `(1,7491,1025)` for 1 batch and a sequence of length 7491 with 1025 features per time-step and you're golden.

Comment: thanks. thats works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an explicit time dimension and a batch dimension. You always have a batch dimension (1 if you are using only one batch) and for recurrent models you need a time dimension as well, as these are sequential models and they operate over time.

Reshape your data to `(1,7491,1025)` for 1 batch and a sequence of length 7491 with 1025 features per time-step.